# How to get a count of all checked checkboxes on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to count how many checkboxes a user has selected. For example, from a group of 10 checkboxes if he selects 5, then I want to be able to count it. Using the line:

```
$(":checkbox:checked")
```

I can select all of the checked checkboxes, is there a way to get the count of all the elements that are returned by that statement as well?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Use the [size()](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/size) method or the [length](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/length) property.  The length property is preferred as it is faster.

Example:

```
var count = $("[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
```

Comment: use input before :checkbox, as without that it is  evaluated as *:checkbox which makes execution slow

Comment: I just reused his example.  I've updated it with the preferred selector taking advantage of the native DOM methods since :checkbox has been deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

Using jQuery:

```
var cbs = $("input:checkbox"); //find all checkboxes
var nbCbs = cbs.length; //the number of checkboxes

var checked = $("input[@type=checkbox]:checked"); //find all checked checkboxes + radio buttons
var nbChecked = checked.length;
```

Using JavaScript:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); //or document.forms[0].elements;
var cbs = []; //will contain all checkboxes
var checked = []; //will contain all checked checkboxes
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox") {
    cbs.push(inputs[i]);
    if (inputs[i].checked) {
      checked.push(inputs[i]);
    }
  }
}
var nbCbs = cbs.length; //number of checkboxes
var nbChecked = checked.length; //number of checked checkboxes
```

Source: [How to find Checkboxes? at coderanch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/120677/HTML-CSS-JavaScript/find-Checkboxes)

Comment: I got `.size()` is not a function - changing to `.length` worked

Comment: @Kenord no worries it happens ^.^