# Checking Number of Selected Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I saw the [is](http://docs.jquery.com/Is) function in jQuery, and it returns me, for example, if any of the checkboxes are selected.

I need to do a check for how many checkboxes had been selected by the user, because my app requires something like "select two of these". Is there a quick way to do it?

Also, how can I catch when the user clicks the "submit" and then be able to decide whether to let the form send or not, according to checks?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count the number of checkboxes selected without reloading the page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304715/count-the-number-of-checkboxes-selected-without-reloading-the-page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the amount of checkboxes checked and bind to the submit button:

```
$("#yourButton").click(function(e){
  var n = $("input:checked").length;  //Checkbox count, may need refined
  if(n<2) //using n from above.
  {
    e.preventDefault(); 
  }
});
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZtTG2/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".submitBtn").click(function(event) {
    if ($(":checked").length < 2) {
        event.preventDefault();
    } else {
        $('form').submit();
    }
});
```