# jquery How to access only checked checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div which contains `7 checkboxes` , i wrote this following code for accessing `only the checked checkbox` into the `array icons`

```
var icons = $("div").find("input[type=checkbox]").each(function () { 
if($(this).attr("checked") == "checked") return this; });

alert(icons.length);
```

but it always alert 7 .Can anybody tell me the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get number of checkboxes that are checked in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697329/get-number-of-checkboxes-that-are-checked-in-javascript) and [Checking Number of Selected Checkboxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994079/checking-number-of-selected-checkboxes) -- please [use the search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+find+selected+checkboxes) before you ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

```
var icons = $("div").find("input[type=checkbox]:checked");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var icons= $("div").find("input:checked").length;
alert(icons);
```

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to assign a class to target inputs and use [checked selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/), see an example below:

```
var icons = $('.box:checked');
```

Comment: whats the need of class if we can do as @mgraph & ThulasiRam answered

Comment: @user1400722 **$("div")** will find every div on your page

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.map`,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var checks = $.map($("div").find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked'),function(arr){
        return arr;
    })
    console.log(checks.length);
})
```

or your method,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var checks = $.each($("div").find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked'),function(){
        return this;
    })
    console.log(checks.length);
})
```

Comment: Well, `checks` will have the correct elements, but not because of `$.each`. The return value of the callback determines whether `$.each` should continue iterating over the elements or not. The return value is the first argument you pass to it. So essentially, your code is exactly the same as `var checks = $("div").find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');`, just more convoluted. There is absolutely no need to use each. Have a look at the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/.

Comment: Yes. I have seen it now, there's no need to iterate. The question was on my mind and I just tried to fix the problem in it style.  Thanks a lot ! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Hiya **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/KzMqB/

You probably just need to check once using `:checked` and it will give you what you are looking for.

good read: http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Hope this helps!

**code**

```
var icons = $("div").find("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
           alert("ID of checked checkbox = " + $(this).attr("id"));
});
```