# Limit number of checkboxes allowed to be checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Count the number of checkboxes selected without reloading the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304715/count-the-number-of-checkboxes-selected-without-reloading-the-page)

I have an order form that asks the User which type of pass they would like (1-3 days), and gives them the option to choose the days they want the pass for.

Currently, when they choose 3 days, my JQuery selects all 3 checkboxes for them, and deselects when they choose 1 or 2 day(s). However, what I'm trying to do is:

When they select 2 day pass, it only allows them to check a maximum of 2 boxes. When they select a 1 day pass, it only allows them to check 1 box.

I'm drawing a blank as to what needs to go in my `validateDays()` function - the best way to go about running this validation or whether this is actually the best route to take.

Every method I think of using requires the checkboxes to have the same Name/ID - but due to other parts of the form (omitted), they unfortunately can't.

Any ideas / pointers?

**HEAD Section JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function validateDays() {
    $('#matthewpeckham').find('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
        var pass = parseInt($('input[name="other_1"]:checked').val(), 10) //1,2,3
        var days = $('#matthewpeckham').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
        console.log(days, pass);
        if (days == pass) {
            $('#matthewpeckham').find('input[type="checkbox"]').not(':checked').prop('disabled', true);
        }
        else {
            $('#matthewpeckham').find('input[type="checkbox"]').not(':checked').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    })
    $('input[name="other_1"]').change(function () {
        $('#matthewpeckham').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop({
            'checked': false,
            'disabled': false
        });
        if (parseInt($(this).val(), 10) == 3) $('#matthewpeckham').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop({
            'checked': true,
            'disabled': false
        });
    });
}

</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#3daypass').click(function() {
        jQuery('#other_2 , #other_3 , #other_4').prop('checked', true);
    });
    jQuery('#2daypass , #1daypass').click(function() {
        jQuery('#other_2 , #other_3 , #other_4').prop('checked', false);
    });
});

</script>
```

**BODY Section HTML:**

```
<input name="other_1" type="radio" value="3daypass" id="3daypass" onClick="validateDays();">
<input name="other_1" type="radio" value="2daypass" id="2daypass" onClick="validateDays();">
<input name="other_1" type="radio" value="1daypass" id="1daypass" onClick="validateDays();">

<input name="other_2" type="checkbox" id="other_2" value="Tues 5 Feb">
<input name="other_3" type="checkbox" id="other_3" value="Wed 6 Feb">
<input name="other_4" type="checkbox" id="other_4" value="Thurs 7 Feb">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a jQuery solution: **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/GH6xJ/)**

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
    var pass = parseInt($('input[name="other_1"]:checked').val(), 10) //1,2,3
    var days = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
    console.log(days, pass);
    if (days == pass) {
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(':checked').prop('disabled', true);
    }
})
$('input[name="other_1"]').change(function () {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop({
        'checked': false,
            'disabled': false
    });
    if (parseInt($(this).val(), 10) == 3) $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop({
        'checked': true,
            'disabled': false
    });
});
```

Comment: This is a great method - physically disabling the box is much more convenient than popping up an alert. How can I tweak the code so that the last box(es) re-enable when some are unclicked?

Comment: Like this you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/GH6xJ/3/

Comment: Perfect. However, I limited the checkboxes to just the one's found within this part of the form (`#matthewpeckham`) and for some reason the validation doesn't work the first time you click a checkbox - only the subsequent times. Have I added too many `.find`s?

Comment: You've replaced your innards of `validateDays` with the events he's described.  Thus, your events will only get bound after validateDays is called (and bound again and again on subsequent calls).  Get rid of the function and just bind the events on DOM Ready.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the number of checked boxes in your validate function:

```
function validateDays() {
    var numBoxesChecked = $("input:checkbox:checked").length;

    if (document.getElementById("2daypass").checked && numBoxesChecked > 2) {
        // invalid
    }

    if (document.getElementById("1daypass").checked && numBoxesChecked > 1) {
        // invalid
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that any javascript validation can be bypassed, so ensure you are performing some type of validation on your server as well.

Also note you may want to change the `numBoxesChecked` selector if there are other unrelated checkboxes on the page, such as limiting it to a container e.g.

```
var numBoxesChecked = $('#someContainer').find("input:checkbox:checked").length;
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly, thank you. Is there any way to remove the last selected checkbox as well? The jQuery suggested in other answers doesn't work.

Comment: @MatthewPeckham you mean ignore the last checkbox when calculating the length? you could add `not(:last)` to the selector: `"input:checkbox:checked:not(:last)"`

Answer (score 1):

jQuery exposes a [checkbox selector](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) that should prove useful here.

Your `validateDays` function can then do something along these lines

```
var checkedBoxes = jQuery(":checkbox:checked");
var numChecked = checkedBoxes.length;
...
    else if (document.getElementById("2daypass").checked) {
        if (numChecked > 2) { /*do something*/ }
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("1daypass").checked) {
        if (numChecked > 1) { /*do something*/ }
    }
    else {
        // DO NOTHING
    }
...
```

However, you might have an issue with "reverting" the box.  You might be able to do simply

```
jQuery(this).prop('checked', false)
```

Comment: Unfortunately the last line that reverts the box doesn't seem to work - Any more thoughts? Code has been edited in initial question.

Comment: you seem to already have a solution, but to clarify - when this answer was written, the `this` variable of `validateDays` should have been one of the checkboxes.  That seems to have changed.  This code would revert the box that had been ticked, but it seems that your function is only used for attaching events, and the `this` keyword will have shifted inside those functions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in this area by any means but here is what I do on a site of mine, you should be able to modify it to suit your needs...just remember to give your inputs the same class name.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Check() {
    var count = 0;
    var checkBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName('chkValidation');
    for (var index = 0; index < checkBoxes.length; index++) {
        if (checkBoxes[index].type == 'checkbox') {
            if (!checkBoxes[index].disabled) {
                count = checkBoxes[index].checked ? (count + 1) : count;
            }
        }
    }
    if (count > 3) {
        alert('Question two - please select a maximum of 3 sub questions to ask.');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it dymanically, using a function like so:

```
$('.checkbox').on('click', function(e) {
  var num_checked = 0;

  $('.checkbox').each(function() {
    if ( $(this).prop('checked') ) num_checked++;
  });

  var max_checked = $('input[name="other_1"]:checked').val();

  if ( num_checked > max_checked ) {
    $(this).prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

Assuming a few small modifications to your html:

```
<input name="other_1" type="radio" value="3" id="3daypass">
<input name="other_1" type="radio" value="2" id="2daypass">
<input name="other_1" type="radio" value="1" id="1daypass">

<input class="checkbox" name="other_2" type="checkbox" id="other_2" value="Tues 5 Feb">
<input class="checkbox" name="other_3" type="checkbox" id="other_3" value="Wed 6 Feb">
<input class="checkbox" name="other_4" type="checkbox" id="other_4" value="Thurs 7 Feb">
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/osecep/1/

It's not perfect, and you'd probably want to clear the checkboxes when the number of days is changed, but that should set you on the right track.