# Add a max `checkable` restriction on checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have 10 check-boxes on the page. I'm looking for something very specific with the behaviour :

1. A variable let's say `maxSelections` can be used to control the max-selectable checkboxes
2. After `maxSelections` is reached, the other checkboxes on the page should be disabled
3. At this time, those already checked should not be disabled as user has to have the option of unchecking something from here to select the other available checkbox

ps I've refered this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vVxM2/) but cant get the point-2 to be working
Thanks in advance for help

```
var limit = 3;
$('input.single-checkbox').on('change', function(evt) {
   if($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {
       this.checked = false;
   }
});
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant code directly in the question body. In addition to the linked duplicate, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001844/how-to-limit-the-number-of-selected-checkboxes) (amongst [others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463238/limit-number-of-checkboxes-allowed-to-be-checked)).

Comment: I have already referenced the question you mentioned, and stated why I'm having trouble with the solution it offers. Sorry to have not included the JS in my question

Comment: You didn't reference the other question in your question, you just linked to a fiddle, but in any case the other question I linked to has solutions to the same problem including the part about disabling the other checkboxes. Check the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2966456/615754) - it only takes two lines of code inside the click handler (or really you can do that in one line if you don't use a working variable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use pseudo classes to get the state of the check boxes

> **:checked** : Selects all checkboxes currently checked
>
> **:not(:checked)** : Selects all checkboxes currently not checked

Once we have these two states available, we can use the following jQuery syntax to set the `disabled` attribute of the checkbox

```
$(<checkboxElememt>).prop('disabled', <true/false>);
```

Here's a snippet that answers what you need :

```js
  var maxSelections = 3

$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
      var currentCount = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length // Here we can get the number of checkboxs checked
        // :checked pseudo selects all teh checkboxes that are checked

      if (currentCount >= maxSelections) {
        $('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', true); // :not(:checked) pseudo is used to select and disable all unchecked checkbox
        } else {
          $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('disabled', false); // Else, let's enable all the checkboxes
        }
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="op1" id="op1" />
  <label for="op1">Option 1</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="op2" id="op2" />
  <label for="op2">Option 2</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="op3" id="op3" />
  <label for="op3">Option 3</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="op4" id="op4" />
  <label for="op4">Option 4</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="op5" id="op5" />
  <label for="op5">Option 5</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="op6" id="op6" />
  <label for="op6">Option 6</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the pseudo classes. I'll do my study of the same