# calculate the number of html checkbox checked using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, forms, checkbox

how can i calculate the number of checkboxes that a user has checked using jquery?

what i want to do is limiting the number of checking for checkboxes in a form to 10 for example and when a user exceeds this range display a warning message.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a count of all checked checkboxes on a page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872296/how-to-get-a-count-of-all-checked-checkboxes-on-a-page)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

There are multiple methods to do that:

**Method 1:**

```
alert($('.checkbox_class_here:checked').size());
```

**Method 2:**

```
alert($('input[name=checkbox_name]').attr('checked'));
```

**Method: 3**

```
alert($(":checkbox:checked").length);
```

Comment: Good answer, but shouldn't you use .checkbox_id_here instead of #checkbox_id_here?  If you use #checkbox_id_here, size() will always be 1, which will be kinda pointless because there can only be one unique ID.  Makes sense to refer to classes instead, where there can be multiple checkboxes

Comment: `alert($('.pairing-cbk :checked').size());` didn't work but `alert($('.pairing-cbk:checked').size());` worked due to the reason mentioned above by @James Wiseman

Comment: It's worth noting  that alert($('input[name=checkbox_name]').attr('checked')); alerts "checked" when the checkbox is checked & alerts "undefined", if not checked. It does not give the "count" of the checkboxes as the OP asked for. So while Method 1 & 3 work, unfortunately, Method 2 does not work.

Answer (score 18):

This should work:

```
alert($("input:checkbox:checked").length);
```

Comment: $("input:checkbox :checked").length; with a space between checkbox and :checked won't work it was happening to me.

Comment: That's because it would be looking for descendends of `input:checkbox` that were `checked`, not for `input:checkbox` that are themselves checked. The space stipulates an ancestor/descendent relationship.

Answer (score 2):

If none of the methods above work, you probably haven't imported jQuery yet.
To import jQuery, paste this code into the `<head>` of your HTML.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

I actually had the same problem while creating a product ordering page, and I wanted it to count The number of products in the cart at the order confirmation page. I referred to this post and tried all of the methods. Then I found out I did not import jQuery, so the `$(':checkbox:checked')` did not work.

Answer (score 0):

you ought to use

```
alert($("input:checkbox:checked").length);
```

or

```
alert($(".checkbox-class:checked").length);
```

if you have more forms on one page

.size() (method number 1 in current accepted answer) is deprecated since jQuery 1.8