# how to count number of checkboxes(across all pages of gridview) checked in gridview using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am in a situation where in need help from you.

i have written below code in javascript which checks how many checkboxes are checked in gridview and display message however its restricted to one page of my gridview only and doesnt work when i move to next page, is there any way that javascript code check how many checkboxes have been checked across all pages of gridview ?

```
function CheckBoxCount()
    {
     var gv = document.getElementById("<%= Gridview1.ClientID %>");
     var inputList = gv.getElementsByTagName("input");
     var numChecked = 0;

     for (var i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++)
      {
        if (inputList[i].type == "checkbox" && inputList[i].checked)
         {
          numChecked = numChecked + 1;
          if( numChecked > 8)
          {
           alert('Only Eight items could be added in final grid');
           break;
          }
         }
      }

    }
```

Comment: you cannot see checked states of other pages, because you are not displaying in the page . (i mean you are not adding into dom). so as every page change, you need to check.

Comment: yes i can implement jquery in my code, any example ? i need a solution which workks across all pages of grid view.

Comment: Js cannot do this, for other pages, you have not checked because of paging, how do you know the number of check-boxes checked when you have not checked?

Comment: yes i understand that so what you are saying is i should store count of 1st page somewhere and then when checkbox is checked on 2nd or subsequent pages i have to add in my existing count ?

Comment: Yes, you should count checkbox checked on the server, not in javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
alert($('input[name=checkbox_name]').attr('checked'));
             or
alert($("input:checkbox:checked").length);
```

if they didnt work check this : [calculate the number of html checkbox checked using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957290/calculate-the-number-of-html-checkbox-checked-using-jquery)

*** dont forget to add Jquery.min.js in your markup

Answer (score 0):

Try the bellow code:

Javascript:

```
function gvCheckBoxClick(currentCheck) {

            var input = document.getElementById("<%=gvRuleList.ClientID %>");
            var chekRowCount = document.getElementById("<%=chkRowCount.ClientID %>").value;

            if (currentCheck.type == "checkbox") {
                if (currentCheck.checked == true) {
                    chekRowCount++;
                }
                else {
                    chekRowCount--;
                }
            }

}
```

Gridview:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Opm_RuleList_ListHeader_Select %>">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" onclick="javascript:gvCheckBoxClick(this);"/>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

use hidden variable

```
<input type="hidden" id="chkRowCount" name="chkRowCount" runat ="server" value="0" />
```