# Fake Check boxes [ with jquery ]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i created some fake check boxes in element [ like `<span>` ] ( after the real check box ) 
they works fine ! all i want is , how can i count the checked check boxes , when a check box clicked ( checked );

i know some ways , like :

```
$(".elm:checked").length;
```

but its not working fine!

i have following code for counting checked checkboxes for example :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".mycheckbox").click(function(){

    $(".checkbox").click(function(){

    alert($(".checkbox:checked").length)); // returns : if check box is checking return 0, if remove checked it returns 1 , its incorrect ! should be if checking return 1 else return 0

    });


    });
}
```

and i know its becuz of my fake checkboxes,
when user click the fake check box , a new function in jquery will click on the real check box , then its work fine!

anyone ? any idea!?

[ sry , My English is poor ]

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/E2kjM/2/

Comment: show us your html code

Comment: [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957290/calculate-the-number-of-html-checkbox-checked-using-jquery)

Comment: you are binding `$("checkbox").click` on clicking on `$("mycheckbox").click` .. every time `$("mycheckbox").click` .. the click event added to jQuery events for that element . one suggestion is keep `$("checkbox").click` out side .. trigger it inside `$("checkbox").click` .. `$("mycheckbox").trigger('click')`

Comment: my html code is : <input type='checkbox' class='checkboxes' />

Comment: @Rab , still not working

Comment: @user2077916 could add this into js fiddle ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/E2kjM/1/ ! 8 mins , sorry :D , what do u suggest ?

Comment: @user2077916 I have added radio select code .. which is part of one project I am working .. hope this code helps you http://jsfiddle.net/e23Qp/

Comment: @user2077916 I will check your code

Comment: No problems with radios ! have u any suggest with my question? :(

Comment: @user2077916 I have updated your jsfiddle  .. http://jsfiddle.net/E2kjM/4/ .. the problem is because of `changing value` .. when clicking click box value not changed .. you should use `change` event to handle this

Comment: it should be lenght+1 to give correct count. inputs with no id nor name are useless in a form your fiddle updated : http://jsfiddle.net/E2kjM/5/ . did you check below my CSS proposition ? :)

Comment: Guys really thx to u all! ♥ u really help me , but it dose not duplicate ! take a look at the question ! i have alerdy answer of " calculate the number of html checkbox checked using jquery " , wasnt help me ! at all <3 thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "change" instead "click".

```
Exsample: http://jsfiddle.net/E2kjM/3/
```

Answer (score 2):

Your selectors in jquery are incorrrect. `$('mycheckbox')` is searching for a tag `<mycheckbox>` in your document, which does almost certainly does not exist.

I presume your fake checkboxes are done via CSS class names on `<span>` elements, e.g. `<span class="mycheckbox">`, in which case you need to do

```
$('.mycheckbox').length;
   ^--- CSS class name selector
```

Comment: dude! what do u think about me! that is just a sample ! selectors are all fine!

Comment: @user2077916 Might want to make sure your example is accurate, it's misleading.

Comment: then don't talk about "fake checkboxes". If you actually did use `<input type="checkbox">` **SAY** so. We're good, but we're not mindreaders. If you examples lie, our answers will necessarily ALSO lie.

Comment: i just hide the real input[checkbox] and after real check box add some elements , they are not real check boxes , i dont what should i say :

Comment: Take a look on my js fiddle ( link on question )

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Let `mycheckbox` and `checkbox` are 2 `classes` for whick the `click event` is `triggered`

```
$(function(){ 
    $(".mycheckbox,.checkbox").click(function(){
        alert($(".checkbox:checked").length)); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Take a look on my js fiddle ( link on question )

Answer (score 0):

why you have click handler inside another click handler. try using `trigger()` and there is no tag `mycheckbox` so i guess you are missing some selector there. assuming its a class.`.`

try this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $(".mycheckbox").click(function(){
        $("checkbox").trigger('click');
    });
     $("checkbox").click(function(){

      alert($("checkbox:checked").length)); // returns : if check box is checking return 0, if remove checked it returns 1 , its incorrect ! should be if checking return 1 else return 0

     });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Counter CSS might do it too :
http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/mshLl

```
body {
    counter-reset: checboxes;
}
:checked {
    counter-increment:checboxes;
}
span:after {
    content: counter(checboxes)' checked'; 
}
```