# How to count the number of checked checkboxes using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of checkboxes for all members that subscribe to a mailing list. I am able to check a number of members that I wish to send to. How can I count the number of Checked checkboxes?

```
    $('#lblCheck').html(checkedCheckBoxes)
    var checkedCheckBoxes = $("[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
```

Comment: You answered the question correctly in the code snippet i.e. `$("[type='checkbox']:checked").length`, Change the sequence of statements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [calculate the number of html checkbox checked using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957290/calculate-the-number-of-html-checkbox-checked-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order was wrong, your code should work if you fix it.

```
var checkedCheckBoxes = $("[type='checkbox']:checked").length;  
$('#lblCheck').html(checkedCheckBoxes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below. It's plain javascript. It shall work.

```
let countCheckboxes = function () {
let noOfCheckboxes = 0;
for(let i=0; i <inputTypes.length; i++) {
    if (inputTypes[i].getAttribute('type') === 'checkbox') {
        noOfCheckboxes++;
    }
}
return noOfCheckboxes;
}
```