# How to get all the checkboxes that are checked jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code:

```
$("#myTable input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked").length;
```

I just want to get the number of checked checkboxes without looping through them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a count of all checked checkboxes on a page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872296/how-to-get-a-count-of-all-checked-checkboxes-on-a-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`:checked` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/).

```
$("#myTable input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
```