# how to get count of checked checkboxes from two checkbox lists using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

I have two checkbox lists, i want to get the count of checked elements of these. below is my code:

```
<div id="divAreaListingByLocation">
  <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chklstArea" CssClass="chkarea" RepeatColumns="6" RepeatDirection="Vertical"
        runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="chklstArea_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
  </asp:CheckBoxList>
</div>
<asp:Repeater ID="repRooms" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repRooms_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div style="height: 100%; float: none;">
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlRoomheader" runat="server" Style="width: 98%; background-color: #86ADD6;
                color: #4A4A4A; height: 20px; margin-top: 10px; text-align: left; padding: 5px;
                font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold;">
                <asp:Label ID="lblAreaName" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="lblAreaId" Style="display: none;" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </asp:Panel>
            <div id="divRoomListingByLocation" style="padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top: 10px;">
                <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkRoomList" CssClass="chkRooms" RepeatColumns="6" RepeatDirection="Vertical"
                    runat="server">
                </asp:CheckBoxList>
                <asp:Label ID="lblRoomMessage" Text="This Area does not have any room." ForeColor="Red"
                    runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

What i want to do is: if user not checked any of the check box from these two then it will prompt a alert to say check one of the checkbox from both lists on the click of a button.

I have tried to it with class but the class is append to the table render in html of checkboxlist.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Please post what you have tried. Similar question have already been asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872296/how-to-get-a-count-of-all-checked-checkboxes-on-a-page.

Comment: @FelixKling the question you referring is different from my question in that question he is asking how to get count of all checkboxes of a page.. and my question from checkbox list..

Comment: @Visions: Well, of course you have to adjust the selector... if that's your problem (which is not clear since you did not post what you have tried), I recommend to have a look at the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/. It might also help to have a look at the generated HTML, not the asp code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using checkbox list it will apply the specified class to the Table not the checkbox. There you will have to use

```
$(".chkarea").find("input:checked").length;
```

This will return the count of all the checkboxes that are checked for a checkboxlist with class "chkarea"

Answer (score 4):

[With jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/):

```
var n = $("input:checked").length;
```

Assuming the asp page returns a bunch of `<input>` elements.

[See this fiddle for a example.](http://jsfiddle.net/9na5Q/1/)

Comment: it is used to return the count of all checked checkboxes of page and my question is i want to get count of checked checkboxes of a checkboxlist...........

Comment: It actually only counts checked checkboxes. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/9na5Q/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use wild card for checkbox list id as the ids generated by checkbox list will start by this id.

```
count = $("[id^=chklstArea] , [id^=chkRoomList]").filter(function(){
            if($(this).is(':checked')) 
                  return $(this);
         }).length;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function fnc()
{
    x=document.getElementById("chkdiv").elements;

    for(i=0;i<x.length;++i)
    {if(x[i].type=='checkbox' && x[i].checked)
    alert("checked");

    }
}
</script>
    <form id="chkdiv">
<input type="checkbox" id="chk1">
<input type="checkbox" id="chk2">
<button id="button" onClick="fnc()">click</button>
</form>
```