# Allow to check two checkbox in Html/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to allow to check two checkboxes in HTML and JavaScript

```
if(checkboxes < 2 ) alert("We must at least select two interests")
```

[image]

Comment: Your description is a little confusing. Show your code, errors you have encoded and what you expected your code to do.

Comment: This could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872296/how-to-get-a-count-of-all-checked-checkboxes-on-a-page

Comment: I don't writing any code I'm just to declare variables

Comment: care to use jquery?

Comment: This is what you want? 
[click here for demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wg0adf45/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
     $('input[type="button"]').click(function(){
        var selected = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').size();
        if (selected < 2) {
            alert("We must at least select two interests");
            return false;
        }
     });
```

Comment: This is dependent on jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You'll just need to apply an event listener to the `submit` event of your form.

When the event fires, count the number of checked checkboxes, if there are less than two you can show your alert and call `preventDefault` on the event object to stop the form from submitting.

See JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/92gf81tn/