# Add the total checkbox checked in the textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a View as below

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitSelected", "Costumer", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form-Costumer", enctype = "multipart/form-data", name = "myform" }))
{
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkall" /><span>Check All</span>
  <div id="checkboxes">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Select //this is from the class where datatype is bool
                        </th>

                        <th>
                            ContactNumber
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            ConsumerName
                        </th>                 
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.transaksiSelectionViewModel.Transactions)
            </table>
    </div>
   <div class="form-group">
         @Html.Label("Total Checked")
         <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="text" id="total" class="form-control" />//the result of the number checked here

         </div>
     </div>


}
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function toggleChecked(status) {
        $("#checkboxes input").each(function () {

            // Set the checked status of each to match the
            // checked status of the check all checkbox:
            $(this).prop("checked", status);
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {

        //Set the default value of the global checkbox to true:
        $("#checkall").prop('checked', false);

        // Attach the call to toggleChecked to the
        // click event of the global checkbox:
        $("#checkall").click(function () {
            var status = $("#checkall").prop('checked');
            toggleChecked(status);
        });
    });

</script>
}
```

The script above only runs to check all checkboxes on each row.

and I want to create a function to calculate the number of checkboxes that have been checked, the results are in the textbox(Total Checked). 
I tried but it didn't work. Please help:)

Comment: please use this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872296/how-to-get-a-count-of-all-checked-checkboxes-on-a-page

Comment: for better understand https://codepen.io/Mestika/pen/aitHh

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a count of all checked checkboxes on a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872296/how-to-get-a-count-of-all-checked-checkboxes-on-a-page)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this when trigger function go on.

```
var checkedCount = $("[type='checkbox']:checked").lenght
```

Answer (score 0):

use this on your document.ready function..

```
var checkednum = $('input:checkbox:checked').length;
alert(checkednum)
```